# Maven plugin crashes when modules are not specified

Tags: maven, maven-module

The Maven plugin goal `database:run` crashes when I try to run it without specifying the modules where it's defined.

My project has four modules (`main`, `core`, `cli`, and `web`) and I added a *database* plugin only in two of them (cli and web), in the standard form:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.tools.database</groupId>
    <artifactId>database-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
    <configuration>
      ...
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

It works well when I run:

```
mvn -pl cli,web database:run
```

But crashes if I omit the module's list:

```
mvn database:run
```

> No plugin found for prefix 'database' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories...

Do I need to also define the plugin it in the `main` module/project, so it doesn't crash? But it wouldn't make sense... would it? Is this the expected behavior? I would prefer the shorter command line, if possible.

Comment: I suppose you have defined the plugin only in the children modules? Not via pluginManagement in the root of your projects ...I suppose also that you have a parent above main/core/cli/web ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, "main" is the parent, and I only defined the plugin in "cli" and "web". I'm not using pluginManagement. Should I?

Comment: Yes you should and define all plugins in your parent...